# replace string in url with ruby regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have this url inside a variable image:

```
 image = http://graph.facebook.com/111111111111111/picture?type=square
```

I want a regex ruby for replace the last string after equal symbol `=` for these urls:

```
image = http://graph.facebook.com/111111111111111/picture?type=small
image = http://graph.facebook.com/111111111111111/picture?type=large
image = http://graph.facebook.com/111111111111111/picture?type=normal
```

the number 111111111111111 is a 15 digits number.

How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Rather than providing you with a regexp that will solve your problem, let me share this link with you: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html, pay attention to "Repetition" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s.gsub(%r{(http://graph.facebook.com/\d{15}/picture\?type=)\w+}, '\1replaced')
#=> "http://graph.facebook.com/111111111111111/picture?type=replaced"
```